# Flutter make simple Facebook menu

Tags: flutter

In `Flutter` i'm trying to make a simple `Facebook` menu, in below screen shot we have number one widget and when i click on that, widget which that is below the current widget, should be resized and grow up and showing another icons into that

[image]

this below code which i introduced reference work fine, but it doesn't have background container

in referenced the link `Column` used and i changed it to `Stack` and doesn't work correctly

[reference](https://medium.com/@agungsurya/create-a-simple-animated-floatingactionbutton-in-flutter-2d24f37cfbcc)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FancyFab extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function() onPressed;
  final String tooltip;
  final IconData icon;

  FancyFab({this.onPressed, this.tooltip, this.icon});

  @override
  _FancyFabState createState() => _FancyFabState();
}

class _FancyFabState extends State<FancyFab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isOpened = false;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<Color> _buttonColor;
  Animation<double> _animateIcon;
  Animation<double> _translateButton;
  Curve _curve = Curves.easeOut;
  double _fabHeight = 56.0;

  @override
  initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });
    _animateIcon =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);
    _buttonColor = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.blue,
      end: Colors.red,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.00,
        1.00,
        curve: Curves.linear,
      ),
    ));
    _translateButton = Tween<double>(
      begin: _fabHeight,
      end: -14.0,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.0,
        0.75,
        curve: _curve,
      ),
    ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  animate() {
    if (!isOpened) {
      _animationController.forward();
    } else {
      _animationController.reverse();
    }
    isOpened = !isOpened;
  }

  Widget add() {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: null,
        tooltip: 'Add',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget image() {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: null,
        tooltip: 'Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.image),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget inbox() {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: null,
        tooltip: 'Inbox',
        child: Icon(Icons.inbox),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget toggle() {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: _buttonColor.value,
        onPressed: animate,
        tooltip: 'Toggle',
        child: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
          progress: _animateIcon,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 3.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: add(),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 2.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: image(),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: inbox(),
        ),
        toggle(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use this widget into `Flutter` listview, that should be appear where i clicked, for example you suppose i have i `IconButton` into `ListView` items, when i click on that, this widget should be appear on clicked position and `Button` should be `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: Here is something very similar that you can achieve with `FloatingActionButton`
https://medium.com/@agungsurya/create-a-simple-animated-floatingactionbutton-in-flutter-2d24f37cfbcc

Comment: @ASADHAMEED you right, how about implementing background container?

Comment: let me try this out myself first. I will share the code soon.

Comment: Couldn't implement what you want. If I find a solution later, I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 4):

I implemented this using `Stack` and  `AnimatedContainer`.

- using `Positioned` in `Stack` , I placed it at bottom. The reason for this is to align both the `Container` and `FAB` in same position when its animate.
- using `AnimatedContainer`, I made a simple animation that changes its height when we tap on `FAB` using bool value.

(I Add one extra container in column, it will hide behind FAB and also Align it perfectly, but you can add SizedBox or Container without color and keep its size as 54.0 at last, if you're not using list.generate)

Try this on **DartPad**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
          width: 250,
          height: 250,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: YellowBird(),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBird({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YellowBirdState createState() => _YellowBirdState();
}

class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
  bool animate = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
      children: [
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: AnimatedContainer(
            width: 54.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.redAccent,
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(360))
            ),
            height: animate ? 56.0 : 250.0,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: animate
                ? Container()
                : Column(
                    children: List.generate(
                        4,
                        (i) => Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              ),
                           ),
                        ),
                     ),
                  ),
               ),
            ),
      Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          child: Icon(animate ? Icons.menu : Icons.close, size: 30),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  animate = !animate;
                });
              })),
    ]);
  }
}
```

[image]

let me know if this work or Is they anything to change from this.

Comment: I think you don't read my question carefully. How can I open this widget on clicked position in listview. Each list items should be have this feature and when we click on that. This widget should appear the same position which button in into list view

Comment: I'm sorry. Did you mean, if you have 4 icon in `listview`, when you click one of the icon then the remaining icon should resize into that in same Position and grow up to show other icons in extended container?

Comment: no, my idea doesn't have more items in menu and my idea is very basic of of that

Comment: Do you have any gif of what you need ?

Comment: you can view this image, `https://imgur.com/a/XotoKuz`

Comment: I see, you mean FAB which we click to open should compress and resize according animated container size and move up at top.

Comment: `FAB` is fixed like with `IconButton`, container below of that should compress and resize according animated container size, and if growing up of this container doesn't have any space, it could grow down

Answer (score 0):

hi please look at this library ... https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal
this is the simplest way to create an overlay in Flutter ...

```
PortalEntry(
  visible: isMenuVisible, //true Or False
  portalAnchor: Alignment.topLeft,
  childAnchor: Alignment.topRight,
  portal: TheMenuWidget, // option 1 + option 2 (White)
  child: MyButton, // show Menu Button (Grey) 
)
```

[image]